# Will this algorithm be O(1) or O(n) space complexity

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, space-complexity

I have a homework question that is asking me to find a missing number in an array with an O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity program.

I feel like I have a pretty good grasp of what constitutes O(1) space complexity, however I am unsure of whether assigning a variable to be the largest value in the given array would make it O(n) space complexity. The code below is what I have written specifically

```py
def findMissing(A):
    greatest = 0
    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] > greatest:
            greatest = A[i]
```

I am thinking it would still be O(1) because the O(n) that I am trying to stay under is the full array containing the greatest value as well as all the other values, but at the same time my variable is still related to the input size, so I am unsure.

Comment: That is O(n) because it is possible that the greatest item is the last in your loop.

Comment: The auxiliary space remains constant as `n` grows. So the space complexity would be O(1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your code loops through the array once, it has O(n) time complexity. Storage only maintains 1 variable so it has O(1) space complexity. I'm assuming you left off the return statement for the sake of the question, otherwise, be sure you include that too.

Comment: Size of the input is `n`. If the function needs to read the array, the space complexity will be `O(n)`.

Comment: @OmG I think you're technically right, but usually on interview questions and the such, they're referring to extra space for space complexity.

Comment: Yeah I left out a decent bit of my code since I want to figure the rest out myself, thank you for the helpful answer